# How to print formatted python output for javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, cgi, stdout

I am trying to capture the stdout when I print on shell. I get output like this:

```
************* STARTING healthmonitor ***********************

Aug 28, 2014 5:17:58 AM org.rzo.yajsw.os.posix.PosixService getPid
INFO: wrapper pid file: /var/run/wrapper.healthmonitor.pid
Aug 28, 2014 5:17:58 AM org.rzo.yajsw.os.posix.PosixService startProcess
INFO: calling "/usr/bin/java" "-Dwrapper.pidfile=/va/run/wrapper.healthmonitor.pid"              
Aug 28, 2014 5:17:58 AM org.rzo.yajsw.os.posix.PosixService getPid
INFO: wrapper pid file: /var/run/wrapper.healthmonitor.pid
Aug 28, 2014 5:18:00 AM org.rzo.yajsw.os.posix.PosixService getPid
INFO: wrapper pid file: /var/run/wrapper.healthmonitor.pid
```

However, when I use the same output to print on a webpage, the format gets jumbled like this:

************* STARTING healthmonitor *********************** Aug 28, 2014 4:48:23 AM org.rzo.yajsw.os.posix.PosixService getPid INFO: wrapper pid file: /var/run/wrapper.healthmonitor.pid Aug 28, 2014 4:48:23 AM org.rzo.yajsw.os.posix.PosixService startProcess INFO: calling "/usr/bin/java" "-Dwrapper.pidfile=/var/run/wrapper.healthmonitor.pid" "-Dwrapper.service=true" "-Dwrapper.visible=false" "-Djna_tmpdir=/app/sterling/jsw/healthmonitor/bin/../tmp" "-jar" "/app/sterling/jsw/healthmonitor/wrapper.jar" "-c" "/app/sterling/jsw/healthmonitor/conf/wrapper.conf" Aug 28, 2014 4:48:23 AM org.rzo.yajsw.os.posix.PosixService getPid INFO:

The python script which prints this is called in a java script file using cgi python way of calling.  And in the python script, this is how its printed.

```
import cgi, cgitb

print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print """
<html><head></head>
<body>
<br>
"""
print nova.servers.get_console_output(VMID)

print """
</body></html>
"""
```

The "print nova.servers.get_console_output(VMID)" is the one that produces the console output.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Wrap `nova.servers.get_console_output(VMID)` in a `<p>`

Comment: @shaktimaan, did you mean a `<pre>`?  I don't believe newlines are honored in a `<p>`, but I know for sure they are in a `<pre>`.  An alternative would be `print nova.servers.get_console_output(VMID).replace("\n", "<br>")`

Comment: @sberry Yup, my bad. Meant `<pre>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newline characters (`\n`) are not translated to new lines when rendered as HTML.  You can use a `<pre>` tag (preformatted) to allow them to have meaning when being rendered.

```
...
print """
<html><head></head>
<body>
<br>
<pre>
"""
print nova.servers.get_console_output(VMID)

print """
</pre>
</body></html>
"""
```

Or you could replace newline characters with a `<br>`, like so:

```
print nova.servers.get_console_output(VMID).replace("\n", "<br>")
```

Either one should do what you want.

Comment: You missed the closing `</pre>`

Comment: sberry, I can't express enough how good it looks now!  Thank you so much!! Awesome!!